# why it fail to execute node main.js in cmd and terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning about node.js and making some discord bots with tutorials in Youtube, I followed the steps for but some reason the code doesn't execute and I even made hello world in another js file to check if there's an error however it dint do anything and no error, I cant find any solution on internet

The steps I followed

--> Installed node

--> Installed VS Studio

--> Made js file using cmd

--> installed discord.js

PS(I also try running console.log('Hello World'); but nothing happen, I just barely notice my
cmd trying to execute since the header change to node .

Here's my dir

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgAfN.png

And the code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Im Online');
})

client.login('myToken');
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if that's all the code you're using, but if it is, then you have to define "Discord" in order to create a new client. Also, make sure to set a bot token if you haven't yet.

So, your code should look like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Im Online');
})

client.login('TOKEN');
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCWNd.png)

Comment: I'm very sorry of my clumsiness but I have that " const Discord = require('discord.js') " and I knew about the token part I just wanted to hide to token